# Qt Save XML File Automaticly

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have this code for saving an XML file and it is working, but in this code the user can set the file name and the location, and what I need is to save my xml file automatically without it prompting the user to choose the file name or the location

```
void filech::saveMission(){



 QString  fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName( this,  "Save a mission" , "C:/Users/",  "KML files (*.kml)"  );

      if ( !fileName.isEmpty() ) {
          manager->saveRoute(fileName);

       }



    myMission.saveMission(wpList,fileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you just need to split it out and overload the functions:

```
void filech::saveAsMission(){
 QString  fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName( this,  "Save a mission" , "C:/Users/",  "KML files (*.kml)"  );
 saveMission(fileName);
}

void filech::saveMission(){
    saveMission(m_fileName);
}

void filech::saveMission(QString fileName){
     if ( !fileName.isEmpty() ) {
          manager->saveRoute(fileName);
          m_fileName = fileName;
       }
    myMission.saveMission(wpList,fileName);
}
```

`m_fileName` being a class variable of type QString;

Comment: thx for the idea 
but it give me this : 

QFSFileEngine::open: No file name specified

Comment: @user2216648 You have to populate the file name with something. In the constructor set m_fileName as m_fileName("mission.xml") or something. A naming convention is something you are going to have to decide.